# How to construct a matrix $A+B$ which is negative definite, with $A$ and $B$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For simplicity, consider symmetric matrices (but otherwise is fine too).

A real symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite if for every real non-zero vector $x$:
    \begin{gather*}
 x^T A x > 0
 \end{gather*}
where $x^T A x$ is a scalar. Reverse the condition for negative definiteness.

Given this, there should be three conditions to satisfy:
    \begin{gather*}
 x^T A x > 0\\
 x^T B x > 0\\
 x^T (A+B)x < 0
 \end{gather*}

I'm not sure how to proceed from here to construct an example of $A$ and $B$ which satisfy this.

Comment: That's impossible. The sum of the first two equation contradicts the third one.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.  Are you sure that we didn't mean positive _semidefinite_?

Comment: This was a question I came across - it was very clear about positive definite. I apologise for wasting your time if it is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to find such matrices $A$ and $B$. Note that by linearity
$$x^T (A+B)x=x^T Ax+x^T Bx.$$
Therefore if $x^T Ax>0$ and  $x^T Bx\geq 0$ then $x^T (A+B)x>0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess there was a typo in what I was reading!